# Extract entry within single quotes but not the comma of the column

Tags: awk

I have the following input file, `input.txt`:

```
\ { 'lhs' : '0',  'rhs' : '\emptyset' },
\ { 'lhs' : '6',  'rhs' : '\partial' }
```

I would like to extract

```
0 \emptyset
6 \partial
```

My attempt was to extract the 5th and 8th columns of interest:

`awk  '{print $(5) $(8)}' input.txt`

This produces:

```
'0','\emptyset'
'6','\partial'
```

How can I (a) extract entries within the single quotes in both columns, and, (b) not extract the `,` after the 5th column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F '[:,[:blank:]]+' '{gsub(/\047/, ""); print $4, $6}' file

0 \emptyset
6 \partial
```

Here `-F '[:,[:blank:]]+` sets 1+ of `,` or `:` or whitespace as field delimiter.

Comment: I will have to work on understanding the -F part. Could you explain what is going on with the gsub() function in your answer? Thanks. This worked just fine.

Comment: `[:,[:blank:]]+` is a regular expression that uses a bracket expression `[...]`. Inside that `[...]`each character is matched individually. So in short it matches one or more of the symbols present inside and those are `:` or `,` or `[[:blank:]]` (space or tab)

Comment: Yes, I was able to understand that part. The gsub part is not yet clear. You are replacing `/\047` with `""` in every row, am I right?  If yes, it is not clear what this accomplishes. Is `/\047` ascii code for `'` ? or something like that?

Comment: Yes that’s right \047 is single quote octal value